# Change Meta Title and Description using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to change anything higher than the body tag in Vue.Js? The contents for both these elements is currently stored in the JSON file that is attached to an element further down the DOM tree.

I need to try and inject a meta title and description that can be crawled by Google (ie. It injects, then renders before it gets crawled) and understand the issues with accessing the body element and higher up the DOM tree, as the current Vue JSON is injected using the App ID on a DIV lower down.

I have previously used some jQuery code to address this issue on a Square Space template in some previous work

`jQuery('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'Enter Meta Description Here');`

PAGE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="{{items[0][0].meta-desc}}">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>{{items[0][0].meta-title}}</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Vue.js CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page List -->
  <div class="container text-center mt-5" id="app">
      <h1 class="display-4">Vue Page Output:</h1>
      <h2>{{items[0][0].page1}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container text-center mt-5">
    <h3>Other Pages</h3>
    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
    <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        items: []
      },
      created: function () {
        fetch('test.json')
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(items => {
            this.items = items
          })
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

JSON

```
  [
    [
    {
        "page1": "Company Name",
        "meta-title": "Acme Corp"
        "meta-desc": "Welcome to Acme Corp"
    }
    ],
    [
    {
        "products": "Product List"
    }
    ],
    [
    {
        "contactus": "Contact Us at Acme Corp"
    }
  ]
```

Here is the code in action, the incoming JSON file comes in a fixed array format with the meta details alongside the body elements. Making this a bit more tricky.

https://arraydemo.netlify.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since what you want to change is outside the area controlled by Vue, you just use ordinary DOM manipulation. It would be something like

```
created() {
  fetch('test.json')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(items => {
      this.items = items;
      const descEl = document.querySelector('head meta[name="description"]');
      const titleEl = document.querySelector('head title');

      descEl.setAttribute('content', items[0]['meta-desc']);
      titleEl.textContent = items[0]['meta-title'];
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roy J. That's worked a treat - updated the site now. So this is just vanilla JS but within the Vue method because it is being used on the JSON response right? I'm sure I heard on a tutorial about a certain component way in Vue to work with <head> elements but this will do just fine.

Comment: Didn't want to setup anything complicated. This works just fine for me! You have my thanks.

Comment: @Roy J The title content is change. But if I right-click on the website and select View Page Source, I see the title, description and keywords is don't change

Comment: @SuccessMan View Page Source effectively downloads the page fresh. Anything that is updated in JavaScript will not be changed there.

Comment: @Roy J  So actually this way is not support SEO

Comment: @SuccessMan Depends. Google handles JavaScript when crawling sites.

Comment: @Roy J What do you mean? I said it not support SEO because in View Page Source, the description is not change

Comment: @SuccessMan I know. But it is wrong to assume that SEO does not allow JavaScript. Google will process the updated description.

Comment: @Roy J Yes but it doesn't seem optimal

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Vue Router, I believe that cleaner solution is using beforeEach hook:

```
const routes = [{ path: '/list', component: List, meta: {title:'List'} }]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title
    next()
})
```

But it allows you set only static titles.

However, if you are looking for some SEO optimizations, [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/) will probably solve most of your problems

Comment: Nuxt is using Vue-meta under the hood, so just use Vue-meta in your application.
Vue-meta offers a cleaner way to set, remove, create or update the head tag.

Answer (score 5):

Vue meta is an NPM package for meta-data management:
https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/

Example of how I use it in a vue page component:

```
export default {
name: "Contact",
 metaInfo: function() {
   return {
     title: "My page meta title",
     meta: [
     { name: 'description', content:  "My page meta description" }
    ]
  }
 }
```

If you use Vue Router(that's what I'm doing) you can set Vue meta here so all your page can use it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'


Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(VueMeta)

export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
base: '/',
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
```

Comment: This is the best approach for Vue ecosystem. Vue-meta offers the possibility to update th head tag if needed. Use computed properties for that.

Comment: vue-meta for vue3 is still alpha as of Jan 2024

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the title it is easy to change in vuejs.

In router.js file while creating route you can do something like this.

```
{
    path:"/productdetail",
    name:"productdetail",
    component:ProductDetail,
    meta: {
        title : localStorage.getItem("title"),
    }
    
}

router.beforeEach((toRoute,fromRoute,next) => {
   window.document.title = toRoute.meta.title;
   next();
})
```

use of localStorage will help you to change title dynamically.
unfortunately, meta description is not changing with the same method.