# Vue.js SEO friendly

Tags: vue.js, seo

What's the easiest way to make an already developed Vue app SEO friendly (with all the header meta-tags readable by search engines).

I've looked into NUXT, I'll have to re-build the whole thing again, plus i didn't really like the way NUXT works except for the SSR (Server Side Rendering) part.

Comment: Are you using the vue-router?

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I'm using vue-router. VUE-CLI. and most of the routes are dynamic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Meta Title and Description using Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282040/change-meta-title-and-description-using-vue-js)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `vue-router`, you're able to utilize the `meta` property on the route: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

From here on, you can define a title, description and whatmore, and then use them in your layout with the following syntax `this.$router.currentRoute.meta.title`

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/), for create custom meta tag (for SEO) on each componente that render in a page.