# Vuejs program doesnt work correctly. vue directives are not working

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code in vuejs. The vue directives and title doesnt work correctly.
Though i have included the vue cdn, vue doesnt seem working.
What could be the possible reason. Please help to modify the code so that the page works correctly with the vue directives working.

Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">

  <title> {{ title }}</title>


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="assets/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="assets/img/favicons/site.webmanifest">
  <style>
  .bg-gradient-custom {

            background-color: #367588;
            background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #367588 10%, #FFFFFF 100%);
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .btn-success {
    color: #bfe8ea;
    background-color: #367588;
    border-color: #367588;
}

.btn-success:hover {
    color: #367588;
    background-color: #bfe8ea;
    border-color: #bfe8ea;
}
.btn-success:focus,
.btn-success.focus {
    color: #367588;
    background-color: #bfe8ea;
    border-color: #bfe8ea;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(62, 208, 156, 0.5);*/
}

.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show>.btn-success.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #367588;
    background-color: #bfe8ea;
    border-color: #bfe8ea;
}

.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.show>.btn-success.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #bfe8ea;
}
.error {font-size:small;color:red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);*/
  padding-bottom: 0.95%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 1;

  background-color: #fff;

}


  </style>



</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <!--start here-->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">
            <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="p-5">

                                <div class="text-center">

                                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">
                                        <font color="367588">
                                        {{ title}}
                                        </font>
                                    </h1>


                                </div>
                               <form @submit.prevent="login">

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" maxlength="100"
                                        value="">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="error" width="100%"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="100"
                                        onkeydown="handleKeyPress(event)">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="error" width="100%"></div>



                 <input class="btn btn-success btn-user btn-block" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Sign In!"  onclick="encrypt()"/>
                  </form>
              </div>

                                <hr>

                              <div class="text-center">
                                    <a href="auth/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
                                </div>
                                  <br/>

                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
  <!-- end here -->

    <p v-if="errorMessage" style="color: red;">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
    <p v-if="loggedIn">You are logged in!</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        loggedIn: false
      },
      methods: {
        login() {
          const loginData = {
            username: this.email,
            password: this.password
          };

          axios.post('/api/login', loginData)
            .then(response => {
              // Login successful
              this.loggedIn = true;
              this.errorMessage = '';
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Invalid credentials
              this.errorMessage = 'Invalid email or password';
            });
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help resolve the issue.
I get the following output alongside the login form which is not expected if vue works.

{{ errorMessage }}

You are logged in!

Comment: Sorry, the problem was with div. The root div wasnt nested correctly. When i removed the additional div in the content. it worked since the v-if directives were earlier out of the root div of id app

Comment: 1: `title` shall not work because Vue will listen and make manipulation only on initialized element. Which is `<div id="app">...</div>`.  2: You didn't declare the `title` variable in data section. What you can do ? You can grap the title by querySelector then update it on desired method call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Meta Title and Description using Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282040/change-meta-title-and-description-using-vue-js)